# get only unique record before grouping

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have this table named `votes`, this table might consist of duplicate records with these columns `business_id` and `user_id`. I created a view that will display the count of votes per business but unfortunately the duplicates also has been counted which should not be. Below is my view code

```
(
    SELECT
        `v`.`business_id` AS `business_id`,
        COUNT(`v`.`vote_id`) AS `num_votes`
    FROM
        `connectn_top100`.`votes` `v`
    WHERE
        (`v`.`year` = 2019)
    GROUP BY
        `v`.`business_id`
)
```

The actual data would be

```
------------------------------------
id | business_id | user_id | vote_id
------------------------------------
1  | 12          |  12     | 1      
------------------------------------
2  | 12          |  12     | 1      
------------------------------------
3  | 12          |  12     | 1      
------------------------------------
4  | 13          |  15     | 1      
------------------------------------
5  | 13          |  15     | 1      
------------------------------------
6  | 12          |  16     | 1      
------------------------------------
7  | 23          |  16     | 1      
------------------------------------
```

so the result should be

```
------------------------------------
id | business_id | user_id | vote_id
------------------------------------
1  | 12          |  12     | 1      
------------------------------------
4  | 13          |  15     | 1      
------------------------------------
6  | 12          |  16     | 1      
------------------------------------
7  | 23          |  16     | 1      
------------------------------------
```

so it should be user_id must have unique business_id and business_id must have unique user_id

tried adding another GROUP BY but seems an error.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results so it is clear what YOU mean by "duplicates".

Comment: @GordonLinoff see updated post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count each `user_id` just once per `business_id`, you can use `count(distinct ...)`:

```
SELECT
    `v`.`business_id` AS `business_id`,
    COUNT(DISTINCT `v`.`user_id`) AS `num_votes`
FROM `connectn_top100`.`votes` `v`
WHERE `v`.`year` = 2019
GROUP BY `v`.`business_id`
```

---

Edit: from your sample data, it looks like you want:

```
SELECT
    `v`.`business_id` AS `business_id`,
    `v`.`user_id`,
    COUNT(DISTINCT `v`.`vote_id`) AS `num_votes`
FROM `connectn_top100`.`votes` `v`
WHERE `v`.`year` = 2019
GROUP BY `v`.`business_id`, `v`.`user_id`
```

Answer (score 0):

**hi you can try this CTE to get your unique values**

```
with cte as (  SELECT 
         `v`.`business_id` AS `business_id`,
        COUNT(`v`.`vote_id`) AS `num_votes`
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY 
                `v`.`business_id`, 
                v`.`vote_id`                 
            ORDER BY 
              `v`.`business_id`, 
                v`.`vote_id`  
        ) row_num
     FROM 
        `connectn_top100`.`votes` `v`
    WHERE
     (`v`.`year` = 2019)
    GROUP BY
        `v`.`business_id`
        )
select * from cte 
where row_num > 1;
```

Comment: it says 'unrecognized statement type (near with)' any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From your sample data, It seems you merely need below -

```
SELECT MIN(ID)
      ,business_id
      ,user_id
      ,vote_id
FROM `connectn_top100`.`votes` `v`
GROUP BY business_id
        ,user_id
        ,vote_id
```

This query will generate the output you mentioned.